# Tesselation - return triangles to cpu

Tags: opengl, shader

I use tesselation shader using Bezier coeffs like in http://steps3d.narod.ru/tutorials/tessellation-algos-tutorial.html

I want to use generated pathes in another shader program (my raytracing). How can I send patches in another shader program or copy from VideoMemory to RAM?  Thank you!

Comment: My code on GitHub: https://github.com/FenixFly/OpenGL4_with_OpenTK/tree/master/StepX_Tesselation

Comment: Maybe a [Transform Feedback](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback) is what you want?